# Dynamic Header Line with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, layout, dynamic, view

I have a cakePHP application with a header line. This header contains things like the name of the owner, phone number, email, ...
The owner can change this information, so this header has to be dynamic.
Is it possible to include this header into the layout, so I don't have to include it in every view?

thx

**EDIT:**
I see, I didn't describe my problem right. 
The informations in the header aren't user informations. There should be informations like the name of the owner of the website (or companies name), phone number of the owner, and so on. These informations are the same for all logged in users. 
Thanks anyway. The problem seems to be solved in an other Question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic layouts in CakePHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173434/dynamic-layouts-in-cakephp)

Comment: You can create header element and pass dynamic data using beforeFilter in AppController

Answer (score 1):

yes

assumning the User data is stored in session you can - in your layout - do something like

```
<div id="#header">
    <?php 
     echo $this->Session->read('Auth.User.name'); 
     // echo other User information
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

User can edit his information even after logged in. in that case session data won't be helpful in displaying correct information.

**For displaying dynamic data**

so better you can set the information from controller and display it in view as like this

**Controller**

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    if ($this->Auth->user('id')) {
        $this->loadModel('User');
        $this->set('user', $this->User->findById($this->Auth->user('id')));
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<div class='header'>
<?php
    if (!empty($user)) {
        echo $user['User']['name']; // display the info whatever you want.. 
    }
?>
</div>
```